# Getting numberFormatException Invalid Double

Tags: java, android, numberformatexception

I am putting a numerical value in an `EditText`. Suppose i am getting the input first say "input". then doing `toString()` the input. Then `parseDouble()` that. Say the result is input*2. So i am then setting that in the `EditText`. Suppose,

```
          package com.hasibshovon.unitconverter;

         import android.app.Activity;
      import android.os.Bundle;
       import android.view.Menu;
      import android.view.View;
      import android.widget.AdapterView;
       import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
        import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.EditText;
     import android.widget.Spinner;

         public class MainActivity extends Activity {
// data source
private static String[] types = { "Angle", "Area", "Bits&Bytes", "Density",
        "Electric Current", "Energy", "Force", "Length", "Mass", "Power",
        "Pressure", "Speed", "Temperature", "Time", "Volume" };

private static String[] AngleUnits = { "Degree", "Radian", "Grad", "Gon",
        "Minute", "Second", "SIgn", "Mil", "Revolution", "Circle", "Turn",
        "Quadrant", "Right", "Triangle", "Sextant" };

private static String[] AreaUnits = { "SquareMeter", "SquareKilometer",
        "SquareHectometer", "SquareDekameter", "SquareDecimeter",
        "SquareCentimeter", "SquareMilimeter", "SquareMicrometer",
        "SquareNanometer", "Hectare", "SquareMile", "SquareYard",
        "SquareFoot", "SquareInch", "Acre" };

private static String[] BitsBytesUnits = { "bit", "byte", "kilobit",
        "kilobyte", "megabit", "megabyte", "gigabit", "gigabyte",
        "terabit", "terabyte", "petabit", "petabyte", "exabit", "exabyte" };

private static String[] DensityUnits = { "kilogram/cubicmeter",
        "kilogram/cubiccentimeter", "gram/cubicmeter",
        "gram/cubiccentimeter", "gram/cubicmilimeter",
        "miligram/cubicmeter", "miligram/cubiccentimeter",
        "miligram/cubicmilimeter", "exagram/liter", "petagram/liter",
        "teragram/liter", "gigagram/liter", "meggram/liter",
        "kilogram/liter", "hectogram/liter", "decagram/liter",
        "gram/liter", "decigram/liter", "centigram/liter",
        "miligram/liter", "microgram/liter", "nanogram/liter",
        "picogram/liter" };

private static String[] CurrentUnits = { "ampere", "kiloampere",
        "miliampere", "biot", "abaampere", "stataampere" };

private static String[] EnergyUnits = { "joule", "gigajoule", "megajoule",
        "kilojoule", "milijoule", "microjoule", "nanojoule", "attojoule" };

private static String[] ForceUnits = { "newton", "dyne", "joul/meter",
        "joul/centimeter", "gram-force", "kilogram-force", "kip-force",
        "pond", "kilo-pond" };

private static String[] LengthUnits = { "meter", "exameter", "terameter",
        "petameter", "gigameter", "megameter", "kilometer", "hectometer",
        "dekameter", "decimeter", "centimeter", "milimeter", "micrometer",
        "nanometer", "picometer", "femtometer", "attometer" };

private static String[] MassUnits = { "gram", "kilogram", "miligram",
        "dalton", "pound", "ounce", "ton", "quarter", "grain" };

private static String[] PowerUnits = { "watt", "megawatt", "horsepower",
        "kilocalorie", "joul/hour", "kilojoul/hour", "joul/second" };

private static String[] PressureUnits = { "pascal", "newton/squaremeter",
        "bar", "kilogram-force/squaremeter", "ton-force/squarefoot",
        "poundal/squarefoot", "atmosphere(atm)" };

private static String[] SpeedUnits = { "meter/second", "kilometer/hour",
        "foot/hour", "yard/hour", "mile/hour", "mile/second", "knot" };

private static String[] TemperatureUnits = { "kelvin", "celsius",
        "farenheit", "rankine", "reaumur" };

private static String[] TimeUnits = { "second", "milisecond",
        "microsecond", "nanosecond", "minute", "hour", "day", "week",
        "month", "year", "decade", "century", "millenium" };

private static String[] VolumeUnits = { "cubicmeter", "cubickilometer",
        "cubiccentimeter", "liter", "cc", "barrel", "cup", "cubicmile",
        "cubicfoot", "cubicyard", "cubicinch", "acre-foot" };

private Spinner spnUnitTypes;
private Spinner spnFromUnit;
private Spinner spnToUnit;
private EditText etFrom;
private EditText etTo;
public String value1, value2;
public double fromDouble;
public double result;
// adapters
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptUnittype;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptFrom;
ArrayAdapter<String> adaptTo;

// private OnItemSelectedListener UnitLisetener;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    // spnUnitTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(UnitLisetener);
    etFrom = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etConvertFrom);

    etTo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etToResult);

    // initialize view
    spnUnitTypes = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnUnitType);
    spnFromUnit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnFromUnit);
    spnToUnit = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spnToUnit);

    // initialize adapter
    adaptUnittype = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, types);

    // bind adapter and view
    spnUnitTypes.setAdapter(adaptUnittype);
    spnUnitTypes.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int postion, long arg3) {
            if (types[postion].equals("Time")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TimeUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, TimeUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Mass")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MassUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, MassUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Angle")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AngleUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AngleUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Area")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AreaUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, AreaUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Density")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DensityUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, DensityUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Bits&Bytes")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        BitsBytesUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        BitsBytesUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Electric Current")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CurrentUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, CurrentUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Energy")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, EnergyUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, EnergyUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Force")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ForceUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, ForceUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Length")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LengthUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, LengthUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Power")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, PowerUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, PowerUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Pressure")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, PressureUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, PressureUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Speed")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpeedUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, SpeedUnits);

            } else if (types[postion].equals("Temperature")) {

                adaptFrom = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        TemperatureUnits);
                adaptTo = new ArrayAdapter<String>(MainActivity.this,
                        android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,
                        TemperatureUnits);
            }
            spnFromUnit.setAdapter(adaptFrom);
            spnToUnit.setAdapter(adaptTo);
            spnFromUnit
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                            Object item = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                            value1 = item.toString();
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });
            spnToUnit
                    .setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent,
                                View arg1, int pos, long arg3) {
                            Object item1 = parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
                            value2 = item1.toString();

                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                        }

                    });

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

        }
    });
    String fromstr = etFrom.getText().toString();
    double fromDouble = Double.parseDouble(fromstr);

}


public void convert(View v) {
    if (value1.equals("Degree") && value2.equals("Radian")) {
        etTo.setText(String.valueOf(fromDouble*2));
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: What do you think `numberformatexception invalid double` _means_?

Comment: i dont know. i am a newbie.

Comment: Conceptually, what would you guess `invalid double` means?

Comment: i would guess that either i can not use double or cannot convert to String. :/

Comment: Can you provide useful informations so we can help? What is exactly the value of `fromstr`. Edit your question so that it is clearer also.

Comment: I guess that etFrom is **empty**. Or it contains a comma (,).

Comment: So, before you try to parse, print out the value of `fromstr`. Is that a value that can be converted?

Comment: fromStr is the String i converted to from the input. Suppose i have input ""input1". Then String fromStr= input1.getText().toString();

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears your input is empty or does not contain a number to parse. Try debugging by logging or printing out the value using try/catch

```
String fromstr = etFrom.getText().toString();
try {
      double fromDouble = Double.parseDouble(fromstr);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    System.out.println(fromstr)
}
```

Comment: ok after using the try catch block i am not getting the exception. thank you. but the problem is now that whatever i am giving to in etFrom i am getting the output in etTo is 0.0

Comment: fromDouble is initialized to 0.0. Its not being correctly assigned the value parsed from fromstr

Comment: remove "double" from the try block. You may be experiencing problems with the scope of your variables.

Comment: ya tried that, but no use. the problem is it is getting the value that was initialised. the parsing is somehow not being correct. cant figure out whats wrong in the parsing.

Comment: Print out fromstr and see what you're getting

Comment: Ok. Thank you for all the help. It was my bad. i wrote the try catch block and the parsing outside the convert method. After writing everything inside that method now it is working fine. Problem Solved! Thanks All!!

Answer (score 1):

This exception is thrown when `Double.parseDouble()` is fed `null` or `NaN`. THis would occur if `etFrom` is populated with anything other then a number, this includes it being empty.

You could surround `fromDouble = Double.parseDouble(fromstr)` with a `try-catch` block to handle the state when this is the case.

Comment: `Double.parseDouble("NaN")` is fine and gives you a `NaN` `double` value.